# If two integer triples have the same sum of 6th powers, then their sums of squares agree $\bmod 9$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given $$a^6 + b^6 + c^6 = x^6 + y^6 + z^6$$

prove that $$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2 \equiv 0 \bmod{9}$$

I was thinking of using $n^6 \pmod{27}$ and showing both sides have the same pattern but it's getting really confusing..

Comment: consider $x\equiv 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 \mod 9$ and compute $x^6\mod 9$

Comment: Note that $u^6\equiv 1,0\pmod 9$ for all $u$. So this means that the number of $\{a,b,c\}$ that are divisible by $3$ is the same as the number of $\{x,y,z\}$ that are divisible by $3$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner : Instead of ^6\mod 9, try ^6\bmod 9.  Then instead of $^6\mod 9$ you'll see $x^6\bmod 9$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: what means ^6\bmod 9?

Comment: It's gonna take more than modular arithmetic, because this theorem is not true of $a^6+b^6+c^6\equiv x^6+y^6+z^6\pmod{9}$. For example, $2^6+0^6+0^6\equiv 1^6+0^6+0^6\pmod{9}$. So you need something about equality.

Comment: He's just saying the spacing of `x\mod 9` is bad, and you should use `x\bmod 9`. @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Compare: $$x\mod 9$$ and $$x\bmod 9$$

Comment: @Shailesh Nothing I wrote is a complete answer. I actually showed why you can't use just my first comment as the answer.

Comment: ok thats nice to know and good morning to you

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner : In "\bmod", the letter "b" stands for "binary".  It means the amount of space that appears before and after "mod" is the amount appropriate for binary operators such as "$+$". "\mod" is intended for things like this: $$(a\equiv b)\mod c.$$ ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but; $$x^6+y^6+z^6=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^3 - 3(x^2+y^2+z^2)(x^2y^2+x^2z^2+y^2z^2)+3x^2y^2z^2$$

Comment: Really? $2^6\not\equiv 2^2\pmod{9}$. @AndréNicolas

Comment: Confused cube and square.

Comment: can anyone give an example where $x \neq a$ , $y \neq b$, $z \neq c$.

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd go about finding any examples of numbers that are the sum of sixth powers in two different ways. Google returns no examples.

Comment: [Here are](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/duncan-moore/taxicab/3_3_6.txt) a bunch.

Comment: Or here: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwir7pSa4vPJAhUC5WMKHfiOCsQQFggmMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fmcom%2F1967-21-099%2FS0025-5718-1967-0222008-0%2FS0025-5718-1967-0222008-0.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFS8G6C3_-DZquh51r9fqwOIUzudg&bvm=bv.110151844,d.cGc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(9n+a)^6=a^6\bmod27$,
so only worry about numbers between $-4$ and $4$.
Their sixth powers are 
$19,0,10,1,0,1,10,0,19\pmod{27}$
and their squares are $7,0,4,1,0,1,4,7\pmod{9}$
The sixth powers are either $0$ or $9A+1$;
the squares are either $0$ or $3A+1$, the same $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Write
$$
a^6+b^6+c^6-x^6-y^6-z^6 = (a^2-x^2)(a^4+a^2x^2+x^4) + (b^2-y^2)(b^4+b^2y^2+y^4) + (c^2-z^2)(c^4+c^2z^2+z^4) ;
$$
by Thomas's comment, we can also pair off in such a way that $a,x$ are either both $\equiv 0\bmod 3$ or both $\not\equiv 0\bmod 3$, and similarly for $b,y$ and $c,z$.

The non-zero squares $\bmod 9$ are $1,4,7$, and now some experimentation shows that $a^4+a^2x^2+x^4\equiv 3\bmod 9$ if $a,x\not\equiv 0\bmod 3$. Thus the expression from above becomes
$$
3(a^2-x^2+b^2-y^2+c^2-z^2)
$$
when considered $\bmod 9$; note that this is also correct when the other case ($a,x\equiv 0\bmod 3$) applies. Since the difference of the sums of squares is $\equiv 0\bmod 3$ (by Thomas's comment again, and since $u^2\equiv 1\bmod 3$ for $u\not\equiv 0\bmod 3$), the claim follows now.